# Is there a way to delete/remove navigator in highstock when a series is removed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, navigator

I have a navigator showing multiple series. Now, I want to remove the series from the chart, and one by one, the series from navigator also gets removed. After my last series is removed, I want to remove the navigator as well instead of showing a blank navigator. Is there a way? I tried disabling the navigator before removing the series, but that didn't seem to work.

JSFiddle in the comments

Chart when series removed (navigator disabled), and a new series is added. 
[image: After adding series back, it doesn't show up in the container]

Comment: Please provide a live demo of you chart (jsfiddle ideally).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/WEm4F/

Comment: You could provide a modified options object to the chart after the final series has been removed to disable the navigator?  E.G  `chart.update({navigator: { enabled: false}});` ?

Comment: Thanks @83N, that did help out a little. Able to remove the navigator. But when I need to add the series again, I update the navigator to true which works but other things stop working - like I only see the series in the navigator instead of the chart, or the legend doesn't show up.

Comment: I edited your demo and everything seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/36y45v6L/